# Htaccess how to block unwanted url with pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, block, redirect

I want to block some url and return 401 error. This are the url's i want to block. But this is a just pattern.

```
mysitecom/?p=lancel%20soldes%20amazon%20canada
mysitecom/?p=lancel%20soldes%20kartell%20table%20basse
mysitecom/?p=prix+sac+la+charmeuse+de+lancel
mysitecom/?lancel=bb-prix-wii-fit
mysitecom/page/2/?p=lancel%20soldes%20caroll%20rouen
```

Maybe first condutions could be

```
/?p=
/?lancel
/page/2/?p
```

how can i block this type urls with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^p=|lancel)
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=401]
```

Last line can also be:

```
 RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

for a 403 response

Comment: You are awesome. It works for all url's except
this one
page/2/?p=lancel%20soldes%20caroll%20rouen